# What is the right way to maintain user audit in a system designed to use external authentication?

Tags: database, database-design, amazon-cognito

I am using AWS cognito for user authentication in the application that I designed. And where ever there is a need for user audit in the application, I have used the id from cognito as if it is a foreign key from another table(I am using a relational DB).
Even though this works, this approach somehow feels improper. Is there any other proper way to design this?

Comment: Good question. Does the id stay the same for a user every time they log in, or does it work more like an auth token, that lives for 60 minutes only, and also changes on every login?

Comment: I am using both. Session token is relayed to the Front-end on login, along with that is a refresh token. Everytime I get the token from Front-end along with a request for some resource, it is passed on to cognito to verify the user and his permissions. The user ID being used in my audit tables, is an attribute from the cognito user model.

Comment: The user ID is the best attribute, you're already using the best way

Answer (score 0):

In my application, the user logs in with his email address (common scenario). Hence, by construction the email address is a unique identifier both in cognito and in my database.

My database creates a user id for each new user, and that is the main identifier I use in my app (note that this identifier has nothing to do with cognito).

Cognito also assigns an id to each user (which it calls "username"), but I never reference that id (nor have I ever felt the need to reference it). I have been in production for several years, and I have never regretted this decision.

Upside of not linking user ids:

- full flexibility (e.g. I can decide that I want to create a new user Object in my database for a particular cognito user. I can keep the previous user e.g. as a backup, even though it is not linked to the cognito user).
- less work: i don't need to make sure the ids in my system are in line with those in cognito.

Downside of not linking user ids:

- maybe it's faster to query cognito using the username field than the email field? maybe that could be an advantage for some use cases?

Comment: Mukund, I am an experienced developer and I am using cognito. By sharing my experience/thoughts with you I hoped to either 1) help you (and potentially help others), or 2) learn something myself (if you disagreed with me and pointed out flaws in my approach). Would you mind commenting on my answer so we can discuss our views on the subject?